# Why do my ElasticBeanstalk logs look like this after a recent deploy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After a recent deploy to my ElasticBeanstalk Node Environment, my application logs started looking like this:

[90m2018-03-12T15:28:53.943Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 10ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:28:54.245Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 3ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:29:23.932Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 4ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:29:24.244Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 3ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:29:53.931Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 4ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:29:54.243Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 7ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:30:23.931Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 5ms)[39m
[90m2018-03-12T15:30:24.243Z[39m GET [1m/health[22m - [90m[32m200[39m (0B, 6ms)[39m

**For reference, this is what my production environment looks like:**

2018-03-12T16:25:15.699Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 3ms)
2018-03-12T16:25:25.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 1ms)
2018-03-12T16:25:45.699Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 1ms)
2018-03-12T16:25:55.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 6ms)
2018-03-12T16:26:15.699Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 1ms)
2018-03-12T16:26:25.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 2ms)
2018-03-12T16:26:45.698Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 2ms)
2018-03-12T16:26:55.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 2ms)
2018-03-12T16:27:15.698Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 2ms)
2018-03-12T16:27:25.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 1ms)
2018-03-12T16:27:45.698Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 2ms)
2018-03-12T16:27:55.711Z GET /health - 200 (0B, 1ms)

Notice all the "90m" and "39m"s all over the place - there's also box symbols that aren't displaying on SO. I'm a little concerned, and a little annoyed looking forward, as to what this means. Could this mean something is corrupted, and that my deploy is actually bad, despite it seeming fine from a functionality standpoint? If not, is there any way to make it go away? It's quite tedious to read logs 2 inches from the screen.

I've tried rebuilding the application, to no avail.

Thanks much to anybody who looks at this. I know it's a small problem! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Those codes are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that would usually add some colour to your logs.

Disabling them will depend on the application that is generating the logs -
 alternatively you could use an app to view them that can read the codes and display colour (some examples in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8414/280585)).